# Why are pointers slower in this case

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, tree, quadtree

I am implementing a quadtree. I re-implemented my first draft (full version can be seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30669/quadtree-implementation)) that used smart pointers and references with a version using raw pointers.

But filling the new tree is apparently up to two times slower, why is this the case?

The old versions code:

```
// returns if coordinates fit in the tree
const bool contains(const double &x, const double &y, const double &w, const double &h) const {
    return (this->x < x &&
            this->y < y &&
            this->x + this->w > x + w &&
            this->y + this->h > x + h);
}
// returns if an element fits in the tree
const bool contains(const std::shared_ptr<Rectangle> &rect) const {
    return contains(rect->getX(), rect->getY(), rect->getW(), rect->getH());
}

// inserts an element in the tree
const bool insert(const std::shared_ptr<Rectangle> &rect) {
    // if rect is too big for this quadtree
    if(!contains(rect)) {
        auto sp = getParent();
        if(sp == nullptr) {
            return false;
        }
        return sp->insert(rect);
    }
    // if element theoretically fits in subtree
    else if(rect->getW() < getW() / 2 && rect->getH() < getH() / 2) {
        if(!subtrees[0]) {
            generateSubtrees();
        }
        for(const auto &subtree: subtrees) {
            if(subtree->contains(rect)) {
                return subtree->insert(rect);
            }
        }
    }
    children.insert(children.end(), rect);
    return true;
}

void generateSubtrees() {
    subtrees[0] = std::make_shared<QuadTree>(getW() / 2.0f, getH() / 2.0f, getX(),                 getY(),                 this);
    subtrees[1] = std::make_shared<QuadTree>(getW() / 2.0f, getH() / 2.0f, getX() + getW() / 2.0f, getY(),                 this);
    subtrees[2] = std::make_shared<QuadTree>(getW() / 2.0f, getH() / 2.0f, getX(),                 getY() + getH() / 2.0f, this);
    subtrees[3] = std::make_shared<QuadTree>(getW() / 2.0f, getH() / 2.0f, getX() + getW() / 2.0f, getY() + getH() / 2.0f, this);

}
```

The time filling the tree with this version is ca. `0.001367` seconds for `1000` elements.

Then I re-implemented this function:

```
// Returns if a Rectangle fits in the tree
const bool contains(const Rectangle *rect) const {
    return (this->x < rect->x &&
            this->y < rect->y &&
            this->x + this->w > rect->x + rect->w &&
            this->y + this->h > rect->y + rect->h);
}

// Inserts an element in the tree
const bool insert(Rectangle *rect) {
    if(!contains(rect) && parent == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    if(rect->w < this->w / 2.0f && rect->w < this->w / 2.0f) {
        if(children[0]==nullptr){
            generateSubtrees();
        }
        for(const auto child: children) {
            if(child->contains(rect)) {
                return child->insert(rect);
            }
        }
    }
    elements.push_back(rect);
    return true;
}

// Generate the subtrees
void generateSubtrees() {
    children[0] = new Quadtree(w/2.0f, h/2.0f, x,        y,        this);
    children[1] = new Quadtree(w/2.0f, h/2.0f, x+w/2.0f, y,        this);
    children[2] = new Quadtree(w/2.0f, h/2.0f, x,        y+w/2.0f, this);
    children[3] = new Quadtree(w/2.0f, h/2.0f, x+w/2.0f, y+w/2.0f, this);
}
```

The time for filling this version with `1000` elements takes ca. `0.00312` seconds.

As you see, the second version using pointers is a much slower.

PS: I fill the old tree (version 1) in a loop with

`insert(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(std::rand()%999, std::rand()%999, 1, 1))`

and the new one (version 2) with

`insert(new Quadtree::Rectangle(std::rand()%999, std::rand()%999, 1, 1))`.

*Can you tell me where the reason for the performance loss lies?*

(Look up the comments for additional information)

Comment: How much slower is "much slower"? And did you compile with optimization enabled?

Comment: The OP states: 0.00312s vs 0.00137s. Personally, I'd be quite wary of basing anything on numbers that small, but I'm no optimisation expert.

Comment: Why are you worrying about the difference between 1 ms and 3 ms ? Do you think your users will notice the difference ?

Comment: @PaulR That all depends on what the user is doing. This could be a big difference if he was selling a library that prompted it self for speed.

Comment: References are implemented as pointers, so there is no reason at all to expect any performance differece. **Have you enabled compiler optimizations?**

Comment: That are only 1000 elements in the example, already with `1000000` elements the difference is `0.9` vs `1.0` (peaking `1.4`) seconds. With `10000000` elements it's even a second difference. I am really curious why that is the case. @Manu343726 I don't know how to configure optimizations in my compiler, I'll look into this.

Comment: The logic in the first conditional is different in the two versions.

Comment: There are a lot of differences between the two versions, not just the smart pointers. For example, in the first version, the `insert` function calls `sp->insert` inside the first `if`, while the second version just returns. This is just one example. I'm voting to close because there's no way to answer this, any of these differences could cause the performance change.

Comment: @interjay Snap, I missed that. But that changes nothing neither in the performance nor the execution, because the rect fits in the tree every time and `sp->insert` is never called. And even if, that would make version 2 even more slower.

Comment: Heads up: it makes no sense whatsoever to benchmark code without optimisations enabled. Modern C++ compilers *rely* on that. Furthermore, the numbers you’ve shown us *are* to small to show significant differences. The numbers in your commends (in the range of 1s) are more relevant.

Comment: Your code is awfully slow. I have a quad/octtree that builds in 0.0001 sec for 1000 particles on 1 core (quadtree version using `double`, splitting cells all the way to 1 particle/cell).

Comment: @Walter can you give me a hint or have some code to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
const bool contains(const double &x, const double &y, const double &w, const double &h) const {
    return (this->x < x &&
            this->y < y &&
            this->x + this->w > x + w &&
            this->y + this->h > x + h);  <---- error here
}
```

is not the same as this code

```
const bool contains(const Rectangle *rect) const {
    return (this->x < rect->x &&
            this->y < rect->y &&
            this->x + this->w > rect->x + rect->w &&
            this->y + this->h > rect->y + rect->h);
}
```

the first wrongly says `x + h`, it should say `y + h`.

Comment: It's ridiculous but this really changed a lot. After the correction the time of `10000000` fills in the old version raised to over `16` seconds, in comparison to under `10` seconds with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You need bigger Testdata to have an reliable statement.

You also want to do that 'time messuring' multiply times.

After that you might use an Profiler to determine what your root cause is.

It can be problems with your cpu cache (change of structure) or something slower you are doing now.

Comment: I added bigger numbers in the comments above. Also Time measurement is already done multiple times.